# soap parameter not defined in wsdl

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Hiall
I have to connect to a 3rd party soap service, so i don't have control over the wsdl. It contains the following definitions:

```
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Shared.GlobalServices.DataTypes/PictureListRequest">
  <s:element name="Request" type="s0:PictureListRequest" />
  <s:complexType name="PictureListRequest">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Header"
      type="s0:PictureListRequestHeader" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Body"
      type="s0:PictureListRequestBody" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="PictureListRequestHeader">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AuthCode"
      type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IpAddr"
      type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DateTime"
      type="s:string" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:complexType name="PictureListRequestBody">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DataAreaID"
      type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DateUpdated"
      type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeUpdated"
      type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
      name="CurrentPageIndex" type="s:int" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemsOnPage"
      type="s:int" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:schema>
```

I need to add a parameter that's not defined

```
$params = new stdClass();
        $params->Header = new stdClass();
        $params->Header->AuthCode = $this->authcode;
        $params->Header->IpAddr = "";
        $params->Header->DateTime = "";
        $params->Body = new stdClass();
        $params->Body->DataAreaID = "hrp";
        $params->Body->DateUpdated = "";
        $params->Body->TimeUpdated = "";
        $params->Body->CurrentPageIndex = 1;
        $params->Body->ItemsOnPage = 100;
        $params->Body->AdditionalParameter = $value; // <-- undefined in wsdl
```

But this way the parameter is ignored in the request, it's not even included in the xml.
Is it possible to force soapclient to include and send my parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab a copy of WSDL, add new parameter definition, save it somewhere on the server where your client resides and point your SOAP client to this modified WSDL.
But be warned that the service your sending SOAP request to, may ignore this parameter completely or even fail to decode the XML.

Comment: What an ugly hack :) But it colud be done...and yep, it got ignored by the service... Thanks for your help.